# How to replicate "Available Groups" to "Chosen Group" functionality in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am moving from Rails to Django and trying to convert a Hamper Business website I run. Love Django!!

I have hampers with a number of products. Each hamper has different products. I'd love to be able to use the following structure to move products into a hamper.

An example: Django uses the following to have a list of groups which then moves to Chosen Groups:

[image]

All I seem to be able to get with a `ManyToManyField` is a list box which I have to select by control and clicking to add multiple fields. This becomes impractical and not easy to read.

To take it one step further, I'd love to be able to include a product more than once. For example, a hamper which has three bottles of the same beer. I would like to not have to set up three seperate products for the same hamper.

Thanks so much in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for part of it. I simply added `filter_horizontal` to the `admin.ModelAdmin` class in `admin.py`.

Still not sure how to add multiple quantities, but I'll maybe save that for another day.